# Angularjs bootstrap WYSIHTML5 editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, wysihtml5

I'm having trouble getting this directive to work:

https://gist.github.com/joshkurz/3300629

I keep on getting the **TypeError: Cannot call method 'setValue' of undefined** error.

Here is my plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ezzDZy190ozvN1TQUt2d?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js in your code

Comment: Now I get this error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'setValue' of undefined

Comment: can you update the plunk? try with an older version of wysihtml5 (what is the one used in bootstrap examples?)

Comment: try to replace `$scope.editor.composer.setValue( newValue );` by `$scope.editor.data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.setValue( newValue );`  http://plnkr.co/edit/jMTnmVRNrnCUJ8qZeCHT?p=preview

Comment: The error message is indeed gone but how do I get the content of the editor now? because I tried logging something in the console to check the watch function but it only logged once (in the beginning)

Comment: Well, I've never used wysihtml5 before, so it's not that easy. But look at the source, and the chrome debugger. I have added a `$scope.alertValue = function() {alert($scope.editor.getValue());}` in the controller, triggered by the button, and a `$scope.logValue = function (html) {console.log(html);};` function in the controller too, to log the content of the editor each time it looses focus.
I also added a ng-model attribute to be able to initiate and save the textarea in a variable.


http://plnkr.co/edit/jMTnmVRNrnCUJ8qZeCHT?p=preview